# 15 GB of photos. Should I use Google Drive, G+ Photos or Google Picasa?

Tags: photos, backup, photo-sharing

I would like to use a Google service. As far I know Google has three photo related services.

I am a little bit confused which service should I use to:

- upload all my photos and keep original resolution
- share with my family selected set of photos
- occasionally make automatic enhancements

I am not asking what [is the best photo sharing service](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5494/best-photo-backup-and-sharing-webapp). I would like to know what is the difference between Google Picasa and G+ Photos, how they are related to Google Drive.

Comment: Web app recommendations are off-topic of this site. Sorry about that.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com has just relaunched with 1 TB (yes 1 Terrabyte) of storage.

Comment: @ChrisF I heard about this. However I want to use Google service and  didn't know that Picasa will be retired. They have too many options.

Comment: I posted it as a comment because I know you specified Google in your question so it's not a direct answer, but thought you might be interested anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Picasa Web is "going away" and is being replaced by Google+ Photos. (In fact, if you go to your Google+ photos and to Picasa Web, you'll see that your photos are all in "both" places.) Furthermore, I wouldn't expect to see too many more updates to the Picasa desktop application. Google doesn't want to be making desktop apps anymore.)

Further, since [Gmail, Google Drive, and Google+ Photos now all share 15GB of space](http://googledrive.blogspot.com/2013/05/bringing-it-all-together-15-gb-now.html), it really wouldn't matter where you upload them to, because they'll all be using the same storage.

Therefore, I'd say that you will want to use the tool that's specifically for images: Google+ Photos.

If you currently have 15GB of photos, you'll want to [purchase some extra storage](https://www.google.com/settings/storage/).

Comment: Will they index photo's?

Comment: Define "index". Do you mean add them to the Google Search database? Not unless you make them public.

Comment: No, like if you were to upload them twice in Drive or Google+

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. Duplicate checks? Not as far as I know. Being able to see them all in one place? Yes, [you can now have your Google Drive photos displayed in Google+](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDrive/posts/immERCA18Qm).

Answer (score 2):

According to Google Plus, pics that are automatically backed up, at a "standard" resolution (not full-size, but still quite good at 2048x2048 pixels and videos up to 15 minutes), are all unlimited.

"You can store an unlimited number of standard size photos on Google+." and "You can upload an unlimited number of videos that are less than 15 minutes long and 1080p or lower resolution."

Please check [Google Plus Support](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/156348) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

- On [picasaweb.google.com](https://picasaweb.google.com/) you can change the date of the album from the one  you chose in the picasa app before you uploaded your pics. You can edit location too for the album or one or more/all pics
- If you are being redirected to Google+ use this link when you are logged on Google:
  https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/myphotos?noredirect=1
- If you have uploaded your pics by "autoupload" directly from your ohone and transfer the pics to your pc and upload them with the PC-Picasa-app you can have 2 sets of the same pics from the same date. It it easier to to find them on picasaweb.google.com